# Python Pandas detects the wrong datetime format

Tags: pandas, datetime-format

After loading data from a csv file, I set the index to the "Date" column and then convert the index to datetime.

```
    df1=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
    df1=df1.set_index('Date')
    df1.index=pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
```

However after conversion the datetime format shows it has been misinterpreted:

original date was e.g. `01-10-2014 00:00:00`

but Pandas converts it to `2014-01-10 00:00:00`

How can I get Pandas to respect or recognize the original date format?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your datestrings were being interpreted as month first, you need to specify the correct `format`:

```
df1.index=pd.to_datetime(df1.index, format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

so that it doesn't interpret the first part as the month

```
In [128]:
pd.to_datetime('01-10-2014 00:00:00', format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

Out[128]:
Timestamp('2014-10-01 00:00:00')
```